# Read from text1 and write to text2

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I'm new to shell scripting.

I would like to write a script to read from text1 file and get a value from this file.

This is the content of the text file:

```
L_T4000-Level3-Ouerdia  6679088203.600000   1523.208000
L_T4000-Level3-Ouerdiaa 8230141220.800000   1526.263200
L_T4000-nodeATI_Wardiaa 444039671.536000    4091589798.080000
L_T4000-node_TIS    6663189651.680000   2080241494.000000
L_T4000-node_TISa   6636796103.440000   2044580242.080000
L_International_node-globe  115911592756.879990 22433604426.723553
L_CRS_X-node06788   4801933455.200000   1329.232178
L_CRS_X-node06852   7100165206.800000   1630.996089
L_CRS_X-node06852a  7841650889.760000   1176446198.640000
```

I want to get the first value from the line with `L_International_node-globe` and format this value to float, and write the new value to text file2

In this example the output should be the value '115911592756,879990' and this value should be stored in another text file.

What do you think about this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

text1="/path/to/filename1"
text2="/path/to/filename2"
var=0
grep 'L_International_node-globe' text1|tr -s ' ' '\t'|cut -f 2 | sed 's/\./,/' > $var
$var=$var/1000000000        #the result should be in Gigabits
echo $var > text2           #on every execution text2 should have a new value
```

This script should be executed every 5 minutes, so what do you think about the resource utilisation?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] and show what you got so far, where you encountered any problems and what exactly they are.

Comment: Have you tried the command lines in the answers yet? If not, please try them and let us know if they do what you want.

Comment: Do you want to write to the file or append to the file (write a new file or add a line at the end of an old file)?

Comment: every execution text2 should have a new value

Comment: I think that the edited command line (at the end of my answer) should do what you want. Comments on your edited question: 1. Variables should be preceded with `$` when their values are *used*,  so in the 'grep command line' `$text1` and in the 'echo command line' `$text2`; An integer division can be done in the shell with `var=$((var/1000000000))`, but I would recommend a tool with floating point capability, for example install and use `bc`.  I will look more into the details and after that edit my answer.

Comment: I think a script like this is OK to run every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

### Original answer

The following command line should do what you want,

```
grep 'L_International_node-globe' text1|tr -s ' ' '\t'|cut -f 2 > text2
```

- print the line with the keyword (and value) you want from the file `text1`
- convert space separation to TAB
- print the second field (first field after the keyword)
- redirect the output to the file `text2`

I am not sure what you mean by float. The shell will print the character string, and various programs can interpret it as a number in float format.

### Edit 1

OK, you want a comma as decimal separator. That is done with `sed` substitution.

```
grep 'L_International_node-globe' text1|tr -s ' ' '\t'|cut -f 2 | sed 's/\./,/' > text2
```

### Edit 2

In response to your suggested shellscript I suggest the following modified version,

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
 echo "
 Usage:    $0 <path/infile> <path/outfile>
 Example:  $0 text1 text2"
 exit
fi

# extracting the value

var=$(grep 'L_International_node-globe' "$1"|tr -s ' ' '\t'|cut -f 2)

echo "debug1: $var"

# install and use 'bc'
# calculation; 'scale' sets the number of decimals in the output (truncated)

var=$(echo "scale=3
$var/1000000000" | bc)  #the result should be in Gigabits

echo "debug2: $var"

# conversion to comma as decimal separator

var=${var/./,}

echo "debug3: $var"

echo "$var" > "$2"   # after every execution the output file should have a new value
```

Examples with data from your original question,

```
$ ./scriptname 

 Usage:    ./scriptname <path/infile> <path/outfile>
 Example:  ./scriptname text1 text2

$ ./script-name text1 text2 ; echo '-----------';cat text2
debug1: 115911592756.879990
debug2: 115.911
debug3: 115,911
-----------
115,911
```

Comment: @MekkiBenyounes, You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by "floating point" you mean `[-]d.ddde±dd` "scientific notation" you could use `awk`

```
awk '/L_International_node-globe/ {printf("%e\n", $2)}' text1 > text2
```

You can use specifier `%g` if you want the format to change between `%f` and `%e` depending on the size of the exponent.

Comment: OP just wants to have the decimal point replaced by comma, how about `{$0=$2;sub(/\./,",");print}` instead?